# Python module for Apple HTTP Live streams (HLS)?

Tags: python, streaming, http-live-streaming

Does anyone know of a Python module for HTTP Live streams? If not what would be the best module for creating a simple client that downloads the ts files locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is only to download locally the chunks, you can have a look at [this script](http://pastebin.com/Q7kJRJzf) . It's been written a while ago, it dowloads all chunks in all resolutions ( I used it to mirror data locally, so you might want to hack it a bit, depending what you wanna do )